# AngularJs - Filtering out duplicates in select control

Tags: angularjs

I have a select list of axleTypes, each having a Type property of either a Front Axle or a Rear Axle. I can not seem to filter out duplicate words of 'Front' and 'Rear'.

[image]

**Update:**

Html:

```
<select ng-model="axleType.Type" ng-options="type for type in uniqueTypes">
```

**Controller:**

```
    $scope.axleTypes = API.GetAxleTypes();

    $scope.fixedAxleTypes = [
    { "$id": "1", "Description": "I beam, telescopic type shock absorbers", "Type": "Front", "Id": 1 },
    { "$id": "2", "Description": "Full-floating banjo housing", "Type": "Rear", "Id": 2 },
    { "$id": "3", "Description": "Something Else", "Type": "Rear", "Id": 2 },
    { "$id": "4", "Description": "I beam, telescopic type shock absorbers", "Type": "Front", "Id": 4 }
    ];

    // This Works
    $scope.uniqueTypes = _.uniq(_.pluck($scope.fixedAxleTypes, 'Type'));

    // This does not
    //$scope.uniqueTypes = _.uniq(_.pluck($scope.axleTypes, 'Type'));

    // This does not
    //$scope.uniqueTypes = _.uniq(_.pluck(API.GetAxleTypes(), 'Type'));
```

I am thoroughly confused. And yes, the API works, I copy pasted above data from 
      **Chrome > Network>Response window**

Comment: Not exactly sure what the "(axleType.Type)" expression is doing for your application of the filter.  Since this is a value that would only make sense in the context of individual iterations of the comprehension, which is not the context that the filter is operating in (it does its work before the rest of the comprehension), might it be the case that Angular tries to interpret the expression, silently fails and thus skips application of the filter?  Might be worthwhile to check the console, and maybe add a little console logging to the filter to make sure it's being evaluated.

Comment: I understand what you saying. It seems like a flaw with angular to me that the filtering is occurring before the data is being evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the error that you added in your edit, I'm sure that the reason is what I described in my comment, which is the use of the `(axleType.Type)` expression for the filter in a context where that expression cannot be evaluated.  Since you're not using the expression in the filter implementation, you could just omit it altogether, I believe.

Comment: Do you want me to comment on whether this is a "flaw in Angular?"  By "flaw" I presume you mean "design flaw," not "bug."  Because it's not a bug; it's intended behavior.  So are you just looking for my commentary on Misko's design choices?

Comment: No, I meant the changes to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

What i guess is `API.GetAxleTypes();` should be doing some asynch tasks like calling `$http`.
if that is the case then `$scope.axleTypes` wont be of the array type you are looking for.
The the `GetAxleTypes` can look something similar to this.

Service definition:

```
{
   uniqueaxleTypes:[],
   GetAxleTypes = function($http,..){
     var promise = $http({
       //config
     })
     promise.then(function(response){
       this.uniqueaxleTypes = _.uniq(_.pluck(response.data, 'Type'));
     })
   }
}
```

Then if you bind a scope variable to this `uniqueaxleTypes` it will always reflect the unique values.

Since  `$scope.fixedAxleTypes` is a hard coded value, its working fine.

Comment: Try as I might with your vague/terse solution, I could not get it to work.